# Is there an algorithm for solving a many-to-one assignment problem?

Tags: optimization, algorithms

I'm looking for an algorithm to solve assignment problem, but it is not one to one problem. I know the Hungarian algorithm it can simply assign one task to one agent.

Let's say I have 4 tasks and 20 agents and I want to assign 5 agents to each task (based on the cost matrix). Is there any efficient algorithm to do this?

It will be great if there is a Python library with algorithm like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say that you now have a 20 by 4 cost matrix $C$ consisting of the costs of assigning agents to tasks.  You can make 5 new tasks, each requiring one agent, out of each original task.

To do this, make a new cost matrix $C_{\text{new}}$, which is 20 by 20, in which each column of $C$ appears 5 times.  Use the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) on $C_{\text{new}}$. and you will have 1 agent assigned to every new task, which will therefore be 5 agents assigned to every original task.

Answer (score 3):

> It will be great if there is a Python library with algorithm like that.

Using the matrix scheme suggested by Mark, you could use the Jonker-Volgenant algorithm which is a modification of the Hungarian algorithm.

It is implemented in [`scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html#scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment). Here is an example from the documentation, which you can modify to include your own choice of cost matrix.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment

cost = np.array([[4, 1, 3], [2, 0, 5], [3, 2, 2]])

row_ind, col_ind = linear_sum_assignment(cost)
```